# Find a substring in a table and return corresponding value

Tags: google-sheets, substring, gs-vlookup

I have 2 sheets in Google sheets:
Sheet 1

```
A             B
Kindle .      Book
McDonald .    Restaurant
```

...

Sheet 2
A                       B

```
Kindle Book 1           Book
McDonald Chicago        Restaurant
Amazon Kindle Book 2 .  Book
```

...

I want a formula that can populate the column B in Sheet 2 using the table in Sheet 1 based on a substring match.

I have tried various versions of vlookup but not able to get it right.

Comment: It is possible for `Sheet 1, column A` to contain two values that are in the same cell in `Sheet 2, column A`? If yes, what is the expected output?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - No, safe to assume that case would not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring/deleting full stops and surplus spaces, please try:

```
=index(Sheet1!B:B,match(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,ArrayFormula(textjoin("|",1,Sheet1!A:A))),Sheet1!A:A,0))
```